# Else Statement not working [Ecplise IDE Java]

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote this script but the Else statement wont work.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token**

````
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the secret secret and secure notepad!");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter a password:"); 
    String password = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please confirm password: ");
    String confirmpassword = input.next(); 
    
    
    if (password == (confirmpassword))
        
        System.out.println("Your password has been set. Now entering your Notepad!");
        System.out.println("Here are your notes");
    else
        
        System.out.println("Passwords do not match! Error Code 1");```
````

Comment: See also [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute more than a single line of code during an if else statement in Java, you should throw in curly braces after the conditional of each statement. I have found that doing so also helps with code readability when I am keeping track of where the block of code that is effected by the conditional ends.

For example,

```
if(password == (confirmpassword)){
        
        System.out.println("Your password has been set. Now entering your Notepad!");
        System.out.println("Here are your notes");
} else {
        
        System.out.println("Passwords do not match! Error Code 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x==1)

System.out.print(x);

else

System.out.print(x);
```

After if else statement , without using braces only one statement can be executed.

If we write more than one statement after if else without using braces , it is not considered inside if else.

For example:-

```
if (x==1)

System.out.print(x);

System.out.print(5);
```

In the above example , second statement is considered outside of if .

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple statements?

Comment: @Boomer_Jesus https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-javaif-else-switch-break-continue-jump/#if-else-if